# Meteor - How do I easily store / retrieve images for user posts

Tags: image, meteor

Hi I have an application that stores posts that include information such as name, location etc and also an uploaded image.

Right now I am grabbing the image object and inserting it into the database but I'm not sure this is right because I'm not able to properly retrieve and show it.

Here's what shows if I do a find on that post for "placepic":

placepic: ObjectlastModifiedDate: Tue Oct 07 2014 16:40:45 GMT-0400 (EDT)name: "placelist.jpg"size: 12170type: "image/jpeg"webkitRelativePath: ""

Here's where I'm at so far (it works on a submit event) but I know this isn't right and I haven't been able to crack it - I've even looked at this https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS but it still doesn't make sense) -

var imgfile = template.find('#placepic').files[0];

```
var post = {
  name: $(e.target).find('[name=name]').val(),
  bestfeature: $(e.target).find('[name=bestfeature]').val(),
  address: $(e.target).find('[name=address]').val(),
  location: $(e.target).find('[name=location]').val(),
  neighborhood: $(e.target).find('[name=neighborhood] option:selected').text(),
  //description: $(e.target).find('[name=description]').val(),
  map: $(e.target).find('[name=map]').val(),
  // placepic: $(e.target).find('[name=placepic]').val()
  placepic: imgfile
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you upload your image to the server, and then you want to save image object in the database.
If so, I'll show you how I handled it.
Simply, I upload photo, and then I just save link to it

```
'change input': function(ev) {
            var temp;
            _.each(ev.target.files, function(file) {
                temp = file.name;
                if ((/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(temp))//is image?
                    Meteor.saveFile(file, file.name);
            });
            if ((/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(temp)) {
                Session.set('imageLink', temp);
            }
        },
```

There is place for improvement, when callback from saveFile comes OK, then you should load it to Session(or wherever you want to keep name of it).

And here is the actual save method on server side(from StackOverflow):

```
Meteor.methods({
        saveFile: function(blob, name, path, encoding) {
            var path = cleanPath(path),
                fs = Npm.require('fs'),
                name = cleanName(name || 'file'),
                encoding = encoding || 'binary',
                chroot = Meteor.chroot || 'public';
            // Clean up the path. Remove any initial and final '/' -we prefix them-,
            // any sort of attempt to go to the parent directory '..' and any empty directories in
            // between '/////' - which may happen after removing '..'
            path = "../../../../../public/"; //chroot + (path ? '/' + path + '/' : '/');

            // TODO Add file existance checks, etc...
            fs.writeFile(path + name, blob, encoding, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err));
                } else {
                    console.log('The file ' + name + ' (' + encoding + ') was saved to ' + path);
                }
            });

            function cleanPath(str) {
                if (str) {
                    return str.replace(/\.\./g, '').replace(/\/+/g, '').
                    replace(/^\/+/, '').replace(/\/+$/, '');
                }
            }

            function cleanName(str) {
                return str.replace(/\.\./g, '').replace(/\//g, '');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cool. Yeah I finally got (half of) https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS to work. It stores the images (albeit to a path in the .meteor/local/cfs/files/images which ain't great), been trying to figure out how then to get the url path to the file on the server and save it into a variable. I'll try above. Thanks

Comment: AHA! I figured it out. Your code inspired me to crack the pathing and how to set the path for both saving and then the meteor path for where in the directory files are saved. Thank you - you saved me hours of banging my head against the wall.